# jsPDF autoTable not displaying images with original dimensions properly in PDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

My HTML table displays dynamic images properly on the webpage, however, an attempt to generate a PDF using jsPDF following this example [created on codepen](https://codepen.io/someatoms/pen/vLYXWB) is failing me. I'm getting the below pdf without the image filling the entire width and the height appears to be reduced instead of getting the original image size- I'm using base64:

[image]

I have also looked at several questions and answers here on SO and elsewhere extensively with no avail like this one here [How to get table row image in PDF using jsPDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465155/how-to-get-table-row-image-in-pdf-using-jspdf) and followed this discussion here https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/issues/173, but I don't seem to wrap my head around this.

```
      function createPdf(){
         var doc = new jsPDF(); 
      doc.autoTable({
           html: '#mytable', 
           bodyStyles: {minCellHeight : 30}, 
      didDrawCell: function(data){
      if(data.cell.section ==='body' && data.column.index ===1) {
          var td = data.cell.raw; 
          var img = td.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]; 
          var dim = data.cell.height - data.cell.padding('vertical'); 
          var textPos = data.cell.textPos; 
         doc.addImage(img.src, textPos.x, textPos.y, dim, dim); 
       }
      }
   })
    doc.save("table.pdf"); 
  }
```

The issue appears to do with the width and height dimensions which is dynamic and also the images are further on the right. However, the priority issue is to set auto value for height to provide desirable outcome. 
Anyone with expertise in this, kindly Check what I have used here https://jsfiddle.net/kibika2020/0rtoph6s/5/

```
  function createPdf(){
     var doc = new jsPDF(); 
  doc.autoTable({
       html: '#mytable', 
       bodyStyles: {minCellHeight : 50}, 
  didDrawCell: function(data){
  if(data.cell.section ==='body' && data.column.index ===1) {
       var td = data.cell.raw; 
       var img = td.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]; 
       var dim = data.cell.height - data.cell.padding('vertical'); 
       var textPos = data.cell.textPos; 
    doc.addImage(img.src, textPos.x, textPos.y, dim, dim); 
   }
  }
})
  doc.save("autoble.pdf");
```

}

I'm a beginner and finding this jsPDF stuff really tough than I expected. Take a look and advise me accordingly.
Thank you.